# Using Devise for a single page for login/signup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was wondering if anyone knows a simple way to make devise 'create' an account if it doesnt exist at login, allowing me to use a single page.

Comment: Have you looked around the devise github pages if that helps you any ways. elaborate the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Devise's sessions#create method yields to a block - see https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app%2Fcontrollers%2Fdevise%2Fsessions_controller.rb#L20

So, you'd need to [override that controller's create method](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers), and use the yield to add a new account if the user is not successfully signed in.

Edit: here's a quick pseudo-code example of what your overriden create method should look like:

```
def create
  super do |user|
    return if current_user # successful login
    # Here, if the user doesn't exist,
    # create a new record and log them in.
  end
end
```

Comment: How would you implement this?

Comment: This sounds perfect. How would i go about checking for a failed login ? I understand the concept of overriding the create method just not sure what the check would be.

Comment: Devise provides a `current_user` method. So, it'd be something like `if !current_user`

Comment: Of course, a failed login could just mean wrong password - so check if there's a current user. If not, check if a user exists with that email (in which case it's a failed password), and if no user exists, then it's a new account - so create a User using their submitted login details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to custom your controller and put the 'create' action in it.

Here's the guide for customizing your controller: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers